# rsync: copy selected files from same directory into destination in one sync

Tags: rsync, file-copying

How to copy selected/specific files from source into destination directory using rsync?

my source structure:

```
src ->|
      |--> file1.jpg
      |--> file2.jpg
      |--> file3.jpg

dest->|
      |--> file1.jpg
      |--> file2.jpg
```

i want to copy only **file1.jpg** and **file2.jpg** into destination in single rsync transaction?

what i tried,

```
rsync -avcz --file-from=file1.jpg,file2.jpg src/ dest/ # since it didnt work i did through looping
```

loop:

```
rsync -avcz src/file1.jpg dest/
```

i dont know how to make it simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `rsync` is very flexible there is more than one way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

One solution that comes to mind

```
pushd src/ ; rsync -avcz file1.jpg file2.jpg ../dest/ ; popd
```

Or using shell expansion

```
pushd src/ ; rsync -avcz file{1,2}.jpg ../dest/ ; popd
```

It is more robust to use a subshell instead of the `pushd`-`popd` idiom since with a subshell the command would not get stuck in a subdirectory if `rsync` fails

```
( cd src/ ; rsync -avcz file{1,2}.jpg ../dest/ )
```

Or with a modern `rsync` version it is possible to avoid changing directories because the `./` syntax (available since rsync version 2.6.7) lets one avoid sending the `src` directory name

```
rsync -avcz src/./file{1,2}.jpg dest/
```

Comment: awesome... the last one works perfect as like what i want .
`rsync -avcz src/./file{1,2}.jpg dest/`

Comment: it was working fine from shell but not from python.. is there a solution?

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed are you using python `rsync` module or running `rsync` executable via `subprocess.call`?

Comment: executable via `subprocess.Popen()` tried `os.system()` `subprcess.call()` all throwing same error `no such file or directory` but same command works perfectly in shell